# Wordpress - Less And PHP

Tags: php, less

I'm trying to figure out how to make a mixins.less file using PHP variables.
I made an Admin page and inside it I have colour selector. I want to use that colour inside my less files.

```
@colour: $mycolour;
```

I'm thinking to write a din_mixinds.less file using PHP and inside it to add the text;
And the to include the files in my style.less.

Or how can I do something better like this:

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

   $brandColor = "#990000";
   $linkColor = "#555555";
   $CDNURL = "http://cdn.blahblah.net";
?>
```

But with less not css.

Thank you

EDIT:
Based on Bass Jobsen answer.

Gives me an error:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?>
body{
    background-color: <?php echo 'red'; ?>;
}
```

Doesn't return any errors:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?>
body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to have a php script output a less file rather than try to get the less compiler to interpret a PHP file as a less file.

Answer (score 1):

Well technical you can create a less.php file:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$brandcolor = "#ff0099";
echo "@brandcolor: $brandcolor;";
```

And than serve that file on a URL (web server) and write in your Less code:

```
@import (less) url('http:/localhost/less.php');
p{
color: @brandcolor;
}
```

**update**

> Yes ... I use less.php

I think that creates a different situation, with less.php you can use the following code to solve your issue:

```
$parser = new Less_Parser();
$parser->parseFile( 'style.less', 'http://example.com/mysite/' );
$parser->ModifyVars( array('brandcolor'=>'#ff00ff') );
$css = $parser->getCss();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'parse error: failed at `$brandcolor = "#ff0099";

Comment: the php should return `@brandcolor:  #ff0099;` are you sure there are no typo in your code?

Comment: This is exactly what I did:
I had a file called style.less. Inside it I wrote @import url('mixins.php');
Inside mixins.php I wrote:
<?php

header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$brandcolor = "#ff0099";
echo "@brandcolor: $brandcolor;";

?>

Comment: and when you open `mixins.php` in the browser the result will be equal to `@brandcolor: #ff0099;`?

Comment: Yes ... I use less.php